# JSON regex pattern

Tags: json, regex, jmeter

I am using JMeter to test our API, however (I think) when a string is too large JMeter throws an error. I get a result in normal text, but when I select JSON format in the Results Tree I get this error and I am not able to view the response anymore. When I try a different response with a not so large string, I can view the result with no problem.

```
2015/12/23 15:25:22 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception:  java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
```

etc

Sampler result

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 3-1
Sample Start: 2015-12-23 15:07:54 CET
Load time: 383
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 382
Size in bytes: 16835
Headers size in bytes: 185
Body size in bytes: 16650
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 200
Response message: OK

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Server: WildFly/9
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 23 Dec 2015 14:07:54 GMT


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: application/json
DataEncoding: null
```

This is the request I send to the server

```
{
    "event_id":"592929"
}
```

And this is the response

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Success",
  "result": {
    "data": [
      {
        "Event": {
          "event_id": 592929,
          "name": "",
          "description": "",
          "time": "2016-01-02 22:00:00",
          "venue_address": "",
        }
      },
      {
        "Venue": {
          "id": 1022,
          "name": "",
          "street": "",
          "postcode": "",
          "region": "",
          "Latitude": "",
          "Longitude": "",
          "short_description": "",
          "description": "",
          "facilities": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "Ticket": {
          "ticket_id": 567828,
          "ticket_price": "10.00",
          "sold_out": 0,
          "ticket_url": "",
          "available": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, the depending on what value I send (and thus what result I get) it either works normally and I can view the JSON response or it doesn't and it gives me this big error when selecting JSON on the Results Tree.

This is only when using JMeter. I tried using Postman, and I have no problems viewing the results on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug fixed in upcoming 2.14 version:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54826

You can use the nightly build following installation instructions:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

> Installing JMeter runtime

Comment: When I try to build the Nightly build I get the following errorava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jorphan/util/JMeterException
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
 at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:257)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException    I am running OS X 10.11

Comment: Something went wrong whilst merging files, but its fixed now. The nightly build worked. Thanks!